# UTF-8 nvarchar Romanian letters not displaying in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, utf-8, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with diacritics in my database, it should store words in Romanian. I'm using `nvarchar` datatype, what should I do?

I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Raion
VALUES 
(1,'Chișinău'),
(2,'Bălți'),
(3,'Comrat'),
(4,'Tiraspol')
```

But I end up with entries like this:

```
?oldane?ti
?tefan Voda
Anenii Noi
Bal?i
Basarabeasca
Briceni
Cahul
```

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Raion (
 id int Primary Key,
 denumire nvarchar(255) Not Null Unique
)
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you mean by a problem? you question is very vague. please add appropiate details

Comment: INSERT INTO Raion
VALUES 
(1,'Chișinău'),
(2,'Bălți'),
(3,'Comrat'),
(4,'Tiraspol'), it might to put this, but it put this: ?oldane?ti
?tefan Voda
Anenii Noi
Bal?i
Basarabeasca
Briceni
Cahul
show top 1000 rows

here's the table CREATE TABLE Raion (
 id int Primary Key,
 denumire nvarchar(255) Not Null Unique
)

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO Raion VALUES (1,N'Chișinău'), (2,N'Bălți'), (3,N'Comrat'), (4,N'Tiraspol')`. See the `N` for Unicode?

Comment: Note that this shows that you are composing the insert in a string, like `"INSERT INTO Raion VALUES (" + id + ",'" + name + "')`. This is **the wrong way**. Use `SqlParameter`. Search around for details on how to use it. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix your denumire value with `N` to indicate a Unicode constant string

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE Raion
    ([id] int, [denumire] nvarchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO Raion
    ([id], [denumire])
VALUES
    (1,N'Chișinău'),
    (2,N'Bălți'),
    (3,N'Comrat'),
    (4,N'Tiraspol')
;
```

Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM raion
```

Output

```
id  denumire
1   Chișinău
2   Bălți
3   Comrat
4   Tiraspol
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e91d8/1/0